# Input stream showing result as empty in android

Tags: android, web-services

I am new to android and tried to implement google API for wheather but when I tried to convert input stream comming from api to string I was getting empty string I dont know where I am doing wrong. Please help.

My code for invoking Api on button click is like this:

```
package com.mubu.wheathertoday.wheathertoday;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class WheatherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wheather);
        final String url1,url3;
        url1="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
        url3="&mode=xml ";
        final EditText etCity=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCity);


        Button btnView=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewWheather);
        btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<Wheather> wheatherList=new ArrayList<Wheather>();
                WheatherHandler wheatherHandler=new WheatherHandler();
              String  url2=etCity.getText().toString();


                try {


                  URL url = new URL(url1+url2+url3);

                    //exception can raise Url must be https not http
                    HttpsURLConnection conn=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();

                   String s= convertStreamToString(is);
                      etCity.setText(s);
                 //  wheatherList=wheatherHandler.parse(is);
                   //  for(Wheather weath:wheatherList)
                  //  {

                     //   etCity.setText(weath.getTemp()+weath.getCity()+weath.getSunRise());
                  // }
//
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            //   etCity.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
            }
        });

    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wheather, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here I am not displaying anything just trying to convert inputstream to string and display string in Edit text field. I dont know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure that your url is right. print it in a Log and check it.

Comment: url is fine I checked it

Answer (score 0):

Use this code : (Pass your Uri to this method and do this in AsyncTask or with a a Thread along with a Handler)

```
public static String getData(String uri) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        con.setReadTimeout(20000);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http:// url.php");
        post.setHeader("Content_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepair));

        HttpClient clent = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse responce = clent.execute(post);

        HttpEntity entity = responce.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream,
                "iso-8859-1");

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader, 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line);
        }
        message = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Ex = false;
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access the (HTTPS) URL you are using in your code via my browser and was not able to reach it. I also checked on [isitdownrightnow.com](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/api.openweathermap.org.html) and it seems that the site is down - this could be the reason for getting no data from the URL. The HTTP endpoint for the API is responding though - perhaps you should switch to the HTTP endpoint? e.g. [this call](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml) and [this call](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&mode=xml) both worked for me.

Have you tried accessing the link in your browser to rule out that the website is down?

**EDIT** - I would also support what the others have said: it's better to do network access off the main UI thread by using an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`.

**EDIT 2** - Sorry you're right, as per your comment, you are using the HTTP endpoint but the fact you're using `HttpsUrlConnection` threw me. Why not use plain HTTP connection in that case?

Comment: Actually its https but I am using http

Comment: OK, then I think you should be using an HTTP connection instead of HttpsUrlConnection in that case.

Comment: but when when I use http connection I am getting exception as  : com.android.okhttp.internal.http.httpurlconnectionimpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.httpsurlconnection